# Are there infinitely many numbers such that $ \phi(n)=\phi(n-1)+\phi(n-2)$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, totient-function

Euler $\phi(x)$ function. Are there infinitely many solutions $n$ to this equation:

$$ \phi(n)=\phi(n-1)+\phi(n-2)?$$

Here the vector of prime $n$ which satisfy this relation (source [OEIS A266164](https://oeis.org/A266164)):
[3, 5, 7, 11, 17, 23, 37, 41, 47, 101, 137, 233, 257, 857, 1297, 1601, 2017, 4337, 14401, 16097, 30497, 62801, 65537, 77617, 686737, 18800897, 255080417, 12885295097, 12918324737, 96052225601, 516392008697, 7026644072737]

Comment: Looks like Fibonacci.

Comment: @badjohn yes something reminds me to Fibonacci

Comment: Plenty of solutions.  Pick any values for $\phi(0)$ and $\phi(1)$ and it is then determined for all other integers.

Comment: Iterating gives \begin{align} \phi_{n} &= \phi_{n-1} + \phi_{n-2} \\
&= 2 \phi_{n-2} + \phi_{n-3} \quad \text{(using $\phi_{n-1} = \phi_{n-2} + \phi_{n-3}$)} \\
&= 3 \phi_{n-3} + 2 \phi_{n-4} \quad \text{(using $\phi_{n-2} = \phi_{n-3} + \phi_{n-4}$)} \\
&= 5 \phi_{n-4} + 3 \phi_{n-5} \quad \text{(using $\phi_{n-3} = \phi_{n-4} + \phi_{n-5}$)} \\
&= \dots \end{align} You'll notice the coefficients follow the Fibonacci sequence.

Comment: @Mattos This equation does not hold for all integers, so this conclusion is not valid.

Comment: This has nothing to do with Fibonacci, it's about consecutive values of the Euler totient function.

Comment: So we have $\phi(1)=1$, $\phi(2)=1$, $\phi(3)=2$, $\phi(4)=2$, $\phi(5)=4$, $\phi(6)=2$, $\phi(7)=6$, $\phi(8)=4$, $\phi(9)=6$, $\phi(10)=4$ etc. You can already spot a few solutions here. However, the question asks whether there are infinitely many such solutions. Nothing to do with fibonacci.

Comment: @Peter I didn't conclude anything though? I was just highlighting that the coefficients follow the Fibonacci sequence. Nothing more.

Comment: Yes exactly...$\phi(3)=\phi(2)+\phi(1)$ is a solution

Comment: @Teddy38 Ah, I see.  I read it too quickly.  It is not defining $\phi$ in this way but just asking when it is so.

Comment: Trying this out for $n$ up to 10000 shows that there are quite a few solutions, 23 total, with $n$ always prime. The solutions are: `[2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 17, 23, 37, 41, 47, 101, 137, 233, 257, 857, 1037, 1297, 1541, 1601, 2017, 4337, 6527, 9179]`.

Comment: @MeesdeVries $1037 = 17 \cdot 61$.

Comment: Thanks for that catch! That'll teach me... let me amend my statement to "with $n$ usually prime, seemingly biased towards having fewer factors".

Comment: Conjectures about the solutions : $(1)$ $n$ is always odd (besides the solution $n=2$, when we define $\phi(0)=0$) $(2)$ $n$ is always squarefree. I wonder whether these conjectures can be proven.

Comment: Another interesting question is whether there are infinite many Phibonacci numbers that are prime.

Comment: The $89$ solutions upto $10^9$ ($n=2$ is excluded) approve my conjectures. The largest Phibonacci-prime I found so far is $$255\ 080\ 417$$

Answer (score 5):

I've seen these called Phibonacci numbers. [This paper](https://calhoun.nps.edu/handle/10945/38847) talks about bounding their asymptotic density so presumably there are infinitely many, but I am not familiar with a proof.

They are [A065557](http://oeis.org/A065557).

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to start with $n=3$ because the definition of $\phi(0)$ might be problematic. If we assume $\phi(0)=0$ however, $n=2$ is a solution as well. Starting with $n=3$, the number of solutions below $10^k$ is :

```
? for(k=1,7,print(k,"   ",length(select(m->eulerphi(m)==eulerphi(m-1)+eulerphi(m
-2),[2..10^k]))))
1   3
2   9
3   14
4   22
5   31
6   39
7   47
?
```

With the additional condition that $n$ is composite, the count is as follows :

```
? for(k=1,7,print(k,"   ",length(select(m->(eulerphi(m)==eulerphi(m-1)+eulerphi(
m-2))*(ispseudoprime(m)==0),[2..10^k]))))
1   0
2   0
3   0
4   4
5   7
6   14
7   22
?
```

The smallest solution exceeding $10^k$ is :

```
? for(k=1,7,n=10^k;while(eulerphi(n)<>eulerphi(n-1)+eulerphi(n-2),n=n+1);print(k
,"   ",n))
1   11
2   101
3   1037
4   14401
5   110177
6   1876727
7   10076627
?
```

Apparently all solutions (besides $n=2$) are odd. Maybe this can be proven.

Comment: PARI/GP considers $\phi(0)=2$, which is strange. $$116\ 781\ 757$$ is the smallest solution exceeding $10^8$.

Comment: The smallest solution exceeding $10^9$ is $$1\ 267\ 578\ 227$$

Comment: The smallest solution exceeding $10^{10}$ is $$10\ 250\ 728\ 121$$